# Decimal part summation in next record

Tags: sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (ITEM,LOC,NEEDDATE,QTY)
    VALUES('ITEM100087','LOC000987','01-APR-2024',1.38428);
INSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (ITEM,LOC,NEEDDATE,QTY)
    VALUES('ITEM100087','LOC000987','02-APR-2024',1.38428);
INSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (ITEM,LOC,NEEDDATE,QTY)
    VALUES('ITEM100087','LOC000987','03-APR-2024',1.38428);
INSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (ITEM,LOC,NEEDDATE,QTY)
    VALUES('ITEM100087','LOC000987','04-APR-2024',1.38428);
INSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (ITEM,LOC,NEEDDATE,QTY)
    VALUES('ITEM100087','LOC000987','05-APR-2024',1.38428);
INSERT INTO INPUT_TABLE (ITEM,LOC,NEEDDATE,QTY)
    VALUES('ITEM100087','LOC000987','06-APR-2024',1.38428);
```

Decimal part of the `QTY` column should be added to the next record of `QTY` column and the process will be going on. Here if you see the first record it is `1.38428` so it will split `1` as a NEWQTY and `.38428` as DECIMALQTY. In next record `QTY+DECIMALQTY = 1.76856` so `NEWQTY` will be `1` and `DECIMALQTY` will be `.76856`. Required output is given below:

| ITEM | LOC | NEEDDATE | QTY | NEWQTY | DECIMALQTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-01-2024 | 1.38428 | 1.00000 | 0.38428 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-02-2024 | 1.38428 | 1.00000 | 0.76856 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-03-2024 | 1.38428 | 2.00000 | 0.15284 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-04-2024 | 1.38428 | 1.00000 | 0.53712 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-05-2024 | 1.38428 | 1.00000 | 0.9214 |
| ABC | XYZ | 04-06-2024 | 1.38428 | 2.00000 | 0.30568 |

I have tried with

```sql
Sum(QTY+cast(substr(qty, instr(qty, '.')) as float)) Over(Partition By ITEM, LOC Order By needdate Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as NEWQTY
```

But it does not work as expectation. Can anyone put some lights on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SUM` analytic function to find the cumulative total with `TRUNC` (and subtracting the previous cumulative total) and `MOD` to get the integer and decimal parts, respectively:

```
SELECT t.*,
       TRUNC(
         SUM(qty) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item, loc
           ORDER BY needdate, ROWNUM
           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
         )
       )
       -
       COALESCE(
         TRUNC(
           SUM(qty) OVER (
             PARTITION BY item, loc
             ORDER BY needdate, ROWNUM
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           )
         ),
         0
       ) AS newqty,
       MOD(
         SUM(qty) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item, loc
           ORDER BY needdate, ROWNUM
           ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
         ),
         1
       ) AS decimalqty
FROM   input_table t
```

Or, using a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   input_table
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (item, loc)
  DIMENSION BY (needdate)
  MEASURES (
    qty,
    0 AS newqty,
    0 AS decimalqty
  )  
  RULES AUTOMATIC ORDER (
    newqty[needdate]     = TRUNC(
                             qty[cv(needdate)]
                             + COALESCE(decimalqty[cv(needdate) - 1], 0)
                           ),
    decimalqty[needdate] = MOD(
                             qty[cv(needdate)]
                             + COALESCE(decimalqty[cv(needdate) - 1], 0),
                             1
                           )
  )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE INPUT_TABLE (ITEM,LOC,NEEDDATE,QTY) AS
SELECT 'ITEM100087','LOC000987',DATE '2024-04-01',1.38428 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM100087','LOC000987',DATE '2024-04-02',1.38428 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM100087','LOC000987',DATE '2024-04-03',1.38428 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM100087','LOC000987',DATE '2024-04-04',1.38428 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM100087','LOC000987',DATE '2024-04-05',1.38428 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ITEM100087','LOC000987',DATE '2024-04-06',1.38428 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ITEM | LOC | NEEDDATE | QTY | NEWQTY | DECIMALQTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM100087 | LOC000987 | 2024-04-01 00:00:00 | 1.38428 | 1 | .38428 |
| ITEM100087 | LOC000987 | 2024-04-02 00:00:00 | 1.38428 | 1 | .76856 |
| ITEM100087 | LOC000987 | 2024-04-03 00:00:00 | 1.38428 | 2 | .15284 |
| ITEM100087 | LOC000987 | 2024-04-04 00:00:00 | 1.38428 | 1 | .53712 |
| ITEM100087 | LOC000987 | 2024-04-05 00:00:00 | 1.38428 | 1 | .9214 |
| ITEM100087 | LOC000987 | 2024-04-06 00:00:00 | 1.38428 | 2 | .30568 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pGySczcq)